# Cannot register my Xamarin forms app using the visual studio distribute function

Tags: android, xamarin, google-cloud-platform, xamarin.forms, google-play-developer-api

When I try and follow the follow guide https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=windows I come to the point where I Register my google api access. The guide presses the button to create a new Client ID, but that no longer works so I have to go to the google cloud platform and create one myself, when I do that I choose a web app Client ID. After I enter the credentials in the Visual studio distribution window I get a `Fout 400: redirect_uri_mismatch` error:
[image]

Then I enter this URL into my client allowed redirect url list:
[image]

and when I try to register again I get the same error because visual studio has used a new port.
Is there any way to fix this or tell visual studio to use a certain port?

Comment: I don't know what the post id is you get but you can try to edit the post id follow the link and try again.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64576758/error-400-redirect-uri-mismatch-when-distributing-xamarin-forms-app/64661186#64661186

Comment: Yeah I tried that but I cannot find the applicationhost.config anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dident exaclty fix this but I found a workaround by uploading my aab or apk manually.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).